# Why does the create-react-app template system blacklist package.json entries?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates#the-templatejson-file) about creating templates for create-react-app, it mentions that the intermediate `template.json` file, which is transformed into the root `package.json` file of a template, only supports the `dependencies` and `scripts` keys and no others.

I dug through the c-r-a code, and found an active [blacklist](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/94932bedc09976aeac43615d95906aa2dcfefa1f/packages/react-scripts/scripts/init.js#L134) of `package.json` keys, which suggests an active policy rather than a lack of support.

What is the reason for this blacklist? I'm trying to create a template for redux + electron, and I need a `main` entry in my transpiled `package.json`.

Comment: Such question better asked on their github

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a general reason for this kind of blacklist.